# SRSS TextBox shifts in Header when image hidden VS 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services

I'm using VS2013 to create a List Form.   The header has date/account/page information.   The company wants the company logo in the body on the first page but in the header on pages > 1.   I can do that.   However when I hide the image in the header on page one some of the text boxes are shifting left.  I have tried putting the image only in a rectangle and all of the fields in a rectangle but neither worked.  Any suggestions for this SRSS NOOB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create the rectangle right next to your header image (with the same size) and show it when header image is hidden.

[image]

Hidden property for the image:

```
=Globals!PageNumber <> 1
```

And for rectangle:

```
=Globals!PageNumber = 1
```

Comment: I put a rectangle the same size over top of the image and did what you said and it worked!  Thanks!  Before I was putting the image inside of the rectangle

Answer (score 0):

I bet you could place a table in your header bound to a dataset with a statement that resolves to `SELECT 1=1`, a one liner.

In your first column, place the image. Next, in your second data table column place the labels that have been pushed over.